# Счетчик кликов по ссылке

Tags: ajax, post

Имеется счетчик скачиваний файлов по системе:
Ссылка на файл(на моем хосте) -> обработчик записи в базу по маймтайпам (exe, zip, rar и тд) -> вывод цыфирок аяксом из базы на страницу где лежит ссылка.
Короче..
Мне нужно каким то боком прогонять через обработчик ссылки с яндекс диска.
С учетом того что ЯД разрешает делает правильный редирект если приписать к ссылке расширение вида http://yadi.sk/d/qhDoHEdy6432_A.exe
Либо я как то сложно думаю, либо думаю не так.
В общем пытался аяксом отдавать в обработчик "qhDoHEdy6432_A.exe" но видимо как то неправильно.
Как правильно отправить POST в данном случаем?

Answer (score 2):

1. Читаем основную информацию по работе с [API Яндекс.Диска](http://api.yandex.ru/disk/doc/dg/concepts/quickstart.xml)
2. Ищем [необходимый метод](http://api.yandex.ru/disk/doc/dg/concepts/api-methods.xml) среди доступных
3. Думаю, что в данном случае, будет более уместен cURL, чем Ajax/